# Websites required to work on angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, command-line-interface, angular6

I am working in bank secotor, so I don't have a access to open all websites. But I want to work on angular 6, so which websites are required to work on angular 6 and install angular CLI. please any one can tell me the exact required websites.

Comment: No website is required to work on Angular

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you can get access to [Angular Official Documentation](https://angular.io/docs) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

You can find everything that you need to start development in angular in the official documentation. But there are few other downloadble sources as well. And some books like [ng-Book](https://www.ng-book.com/2/).So the access to the angular official site is not a must. You can find many other resources to learn angular offilne as well.

But you need to have access to www.npmjs.com to download necessary depenedencies.

So to get started with angular development at least you should have access to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

Comment: I have nodejs.org access,but if i am trying to install angular cli it's showing need to access site permissions

Comment: **www.nodejs.org** and **www.npmjs.com** are two diferent sites. You need access to www.npmjs.com